# Get time used by the process only

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw

I have a sample piece of code to check how much time it takes to execute. Hence I measure the timestamp before and after its execution and then compute the time in milliseconds.

However the output is dependent on system load and process priorities. As such I am not getting the correct reading.

How can I get the actual time spent by process only for its execution?

Platform Windows Compiler - VC and MinGW

Comment: Use a cpu profiler for doing that

Comment: Thanks - but I need to capture in code and set profiling

Answer (score 0):

Use Win32 function:
[QueryProcessCycleTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms684929(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks - do we have any mapping function for embedded C++ code compiled using MinGW and VC++?

Comment: Embedded in what sense? Are you talking about "cross-compiling for a different OS"? Then we'd have to know what that OS is.

Comment: Yes on RTOS - but the issue is that the same code is ran on windows simulator and the code is same. Hence the code compilation will work fine on Windows build servers but not Xilinx generating SoC

Comment: So, then your RTOS needs to support that feature.